# How to get custom role ID from Drupal UI?

Tags: users

Really simple, where I can I look up the custom roles and their role id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `People > Roles` (`admin/people/roles`) page you can hover over the Edit links or click on them to see what the machine-readable name is, that is the role ID.

For example in Drupal 8 you get three Roles built in with these Role IDs: `anonymous`, `authenticated`, `administrator`.

In Drupal 7 you can do the same to look them up, only the path and the wording are a little bit different (`People > Permissions > Roles`, `admin/people/permissions/roles`).

In Drupal 8 [Role IDs are now machine-readable strings](https://www.drupal.org/node/1619504) while in Drupal 7 and below they were integers (numbers).

#### D8

```
$user->roles = array(
  'authenticated' => 'Authenticated user',
  'administrator' => 'Administrator',
  'site_editor' => 'Site editor',
);
```

#### D7

```
$user->roles = array(
  2 => 'authenticated user',
  3 => 'administrator',
  4 => 'site editor',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not what I was looking for, but if you inspect the Roles Drop Drop on the People Page then the array has the ID in it.